# Parsing XML in a non-XML column

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

i am reasonably proficient with SQLServer, but i'm not a DBA so i'm not sure how to approach this.

I have an XML chunk stored in an `ntext` column. Due to it being a legacy database and the requirements of the project i cannot change the table (yet). This is an example of the data i need to manipulate:

```
<XmlSerializableHashtable xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Entries>
        <Entry>
            <key xsi:type="xsd:string">CurrentYear</key><value xsi:type="xsd:string">2010</value>
        </Entry>
        <Entry>
            <key xsi:type="xsd:string">CurrentMonth</key><value xsi:type="xsd:string">4</value>
        </Entry>
    </Entries>
</XmlSerializableHashtable>
```

each row will have a chunk like this, but obviously with different keys/values in the XML. Is there any clever way i can parse this XML in to a name/value pairs style view? Or should i be using SQLServer's XML querying abilities even though it isn't an XML column? If so, how would i query a specific value out of that column?

(Note: adding a computed XML column on the end of the table is a possibility, if that helps).

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Does this all need to be done on the Database or are you using a program of some kind?

Comment: Yep, needs to be done in the database - i'm hoping to break some of these values out so that they can be used in another view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get the column to an XML typed column you can use xpath queries to get data out of it.  OTOH I'd guess that a computed column that casts it into XML might work.  YMMV, but it shouldn't be that hard to test it.

You can use [`cross apply`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) to get a repeating group out of an XML valued field.  `cross apply` effectively pokes the value of a column into a table valued function and allows you to join against the results.  [This link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlxml/thread/e24bedf7-ad70-4083-8149-a00b740df950) shows an example of how to do this.

I have actually had occasion to do this quite recently (for the first time), but I don't have a code sample to hand and I can't remember it off the top of my head.  You can use this technique to self join multiple layers in a hierarchical structure within an XML document.

Comment: Awesome, that linked blog post did the trick. By using an inner SELECT which cast that *ntext* column as xml, then wrapping that in a SELECT that did XML node selection i was able to create the exact key/value pairs type view i wanted - all without touching the original table.

Comment: Just for reference, the blog post i mentioned is here: http://blog.beyondrelational.com/2007/11/xml-workshop-v-reading-values-from-xml.html and contains a bunch of helpful examples on how to query xml nodes in SQL.

Comment: @Byron Whitlock - Yes, it's not a pretty sight.  Interestingly, the vendors of insurance policy administration systems are moving in this direction as workflow systems and SOA have become all the rage in the industry.  Given that I build data warehouse systems for insurance companies I'm expecting a steady work stream for the forseeable future ;-)